# I need to enter my form data to databse but shows me a syntax error

Tags: java, sql

I need to enter my form data to databse but it shows me error called
**java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'groups,stdcount,hours)VALUES('1','DBS',' lalith ','Lecture','Y3S1G1','60','1am-3' at line 1**

here is my code

```
PreparedStatement insert;
        
        String subName = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem( ).toString();
        String code = jTextField1.getText();
        String lecturersList = jList1.getSelectedValuesList().toString().replace("[", " ");
        String tag = jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String grpId = jComboBox3.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String stdQty = jTextField2.getText();
        String durations = jTextField3.getText();
        
        //new

        try {
            
            //Insert data to db           
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, username, password);
            insert = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO session(subcode,subject,lecturers,tags,groups,stdcount,hours)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            
            insert.setString(3, lecturersList.toString().replace("]", " "));
            insert.setString(4, tag);
            insert.setString(5, grpId);
            insert.setString(2, subName);
            insert.setString(1, code);
            insert.setString(7, durations);
            insert.setString(6, stdQty);
            
            if(stdQty.isEmpty() || durations.isEmpty()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "All Fields Required!");                
            }
            else{
                
                if(!(stdQty.matches("[0-9]+") || durations.matches("[0-9]+"))){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Should be Numbers!"); 
                }else{
                    
                    insert.executeUpdate();           
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Session Created!");

                    jTextField2.setText("");
                    jTextField3.setText("");
                    jTextField1.setText("");
                }
            }                     
            
           
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AddSession.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AddSession.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`session`, `subject` and `groups` are all MySQL keywords. Make it a practice to use backticks when mentioning column names and table names.

```
INSERT INTO `session` (
  `subcode`, `subject`, `lecturers`, `tags`, `groups`, `stdcount`, `hours`
) 
VALUES 
  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```